# what sort of file has extension ".archive-bin" and what can I do with it?

Tags: archiving

I've downloaded a file ending with `.archive-bin`
Can anyone please tell me what I can do with it?

Is it a binary file? or is it a compressed/zip sort of  file?

Answer (score 0):

It's not `.archive-bin`, just `.bin`  I don't know why you see it as that.  The file is a compressed archive that can be read by mounting it via virtual disc mounting tools such as Magiciso and Poweriso.  You can also extract them via 7Zip and Winrar, which can also package them into the compressed file you now question.